# Using getElementById to dynamically query

Tags: javascript

Just need a small help with my HTML form, I have the following code:

```
<form method="get" action="http://solutions-demo.cust-mta.com/automated/action.jsp">

                  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="updateRecipientNoMsg" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="redirect_err" value="/automated/action.jsp" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="redirect_ok" value="http://thankyou.html" />
                  <input type="hidden" id="gid" name="gid" value="200030053" />
                  <input type="hidden" id="pmobilenum" name="pmobilenum" value="123456789" />
                  <input type="hidden" id="uemail" name="uemail" value="[executor]" />
                  <input type="hidden" id="psw" name="psw" value="password" />
                  <input type="hidden" id="pemail" name="pemail" value="[emailBeingUpdated]" />

                  <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="100"><div align="left"><font color="#ffffff" face="Arial, sans serif" style="font-size:12px;line-height:14px;">Email</font></div></td>
                      <td width="140"><div align="left"><font face="Arial, sans serif" color="#ffffff" style="font-size:12px;line-height:14px;">
                          <input type="text" name="pemail" />
                      </font></div></td>

                    </tr>
                  </table>

                  <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="100"><div align="left"><font color="#ffffff" face="Arial, sans serif" style="font-size:12px;line-height:14px;">Mobile Number</font></div></td>
                      <td width="140"><div align="left"><font face="Arial, sans serif" color="#666666" style="font-size:12px;line-height:14px;">


                          <input type="text" name="pmobilenum" />
                      </font></div></td>

                    </tr>
                  </table>

                  <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" />

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>


</form>
```

It is all working correctly, I am contacting a REST API and pushing an action, that being updating a users mobile number using email identifier.

At the moment I just have it all set so when you click it happens and the number is updated in a system.

But I want the user to be able to input their email and their number and it be for them, as currently for testing I have set it to a specific email so whatever details you put in it always updates the hard coded one.

How would I use Javascript to place the values from Mobile Number and Email into here:

```
<input type="hidden" id="pmobilenum" name="pmobilenum" value="INSERT TEXT FROM MOBILE NUMBER TEXT BOX" />
<input type="hidden" id="pemail" name="pmobilenum" value="INSERT TEXT FROM EMAIL TEXT BOX" />
```

Should Use getElementByID method and turn this into a JSP page?

Thanks for the advice in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server doesn't care if it's a hidden or a text input, so why not cut out the middleman and get rid of the hidden fields? You already have equivalent text fields for the same `name`s so it should work just the same.